# Xquery to find last entry in XML?

Tags: xml, xquery

Is there a simple xquery to find the last entry in an xml document?

Thanks

Comment: What do you understand as last entry? Look at `last()` to get the last occurance of a element list in xpath.

Comment: thanks Morja - i need exactly what you put - the last occurance of an element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(//entry)[last()]
```

plus some padding because StackOverflow doesn't like short answers.

Comment: I don't understand why those paranthesis count. If I don't use them, the function returns two entries.

Comment: If you omit the parentheses, you get /descendant-or-self::node()/child::entry[last()], which selects every entry that is the last child of its parent.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [xpath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) and do something like:

```
/rootelement/*[last()]
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be use of the last() function. Check out the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190985.aspx)

Hope this helps